# Including xml files created at runtime in a C# ClickOnce deployment

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, clickonce

I've been working on this application that creates xml files to store user settings and later retrieve them at runtime (if the xml file doesn't exist). The application works great and creates the xml files under \bin\Debug folder of the application. However, when I deploy the application using ClickOnce, it crashes at launch.

After a bit of research I found out that the xml files are not copied to the directory where the application resides (or the Data folder of ClickOnce). I, then included the xml files (previously created) and set their properties - `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`. And, also included the files in the `Application Files...` list. However, it doesn't still work for me. Can anyone please suggest a right and better way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to store them in the bin? Can you create them elsewhere in the project and just include them in your project by name? THey would regenerate before each deploy right?

Comment: Technically they don't regenerate. Rather they will contain predefined settings but can later be modified.

Comment: So is putting them somewhere other than the bin an option? What kind of application is this?